# Prevent Multiple Shakes Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using seismic with the below android code.

When the user shakes the message box appears multiple times. How would I go about modifying the code to make it so that after the shake it 'stops detecting' and waits until the message box is dismissed before detecting shakes again?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import com.squareup.seismic.ShakeDetector;
import com.squareup.seismic.ShakeDetector.Listener;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Listener {





    public void clickFunction(View view) {


        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Not Signed In")
                .setMessage("You need to be signed in to use this feature.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("Hello", "created!");

        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        ShakeDetector sd = new ShakeDetector(this);
        sd.start(sensorManager);




    }



    public void hearShake() {







            Log.i("wooo", "Shaken!");





        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Not Signed In")
                    .setMessage("SHAKEN!.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();

        }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `new AlertDialog.Builder...show();` I would suggest assigning an `AlertDialog` variable (ex. `mDialog`) and in `hearShake()` simply add

```
if(mDialog.isShowing()) return;
```

**UPDATE:** Make `sd` a global variable instead

```
ShakeDetector sd = new ShakeDetector(this);
//...
protected void onCreate(...){
    //...
    sd = new ShakeDetector(this);
    sd.start(sensorManager);
}

public void hearShake(){
    //...
    sd.stop();
    //...
}
```

Comment: is there a way of doing it not using the AlertDialog? If the user is logged in it won't display the message but will run some code.